# How to use Int64 in C#

Tags: c#, 64-bit, integer, representation, int64

The question is easy! How do you represent a 64 bit int in C#?

Comment: @Lucero, It should be asked and answered on SO. So point to a duplicate or let it be.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

64 bit int is long

Answer (score 16):

[System.Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) is the .net type, [in C# it's also called long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

A signed 64 bit integer is `long`, an unsigned is `ulong`.

The corresponding types in the framwwork are `System.Int64` and `System.UInt64`, respectively.

Example:

```
long bigNumber = 9223372036854775807;
```

Answer (score 5):

By using the **long** data type, or **ulong** for unsigned.

[Table of Integral C# Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)